# How to build Spark 1.1.0 on Windows 8?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm attempting to build Apache Spark 1.1.0 on Windows 8.

I've installed all prerequisites (except Hadoop) and ran `sbt/sbt assembly` while in the root directory. After downloading many files, I'm getting an error after the line:

```
Set current project to root <in build file:C:/.../spark-0.9.0-incubating/>". The error is: 
[error] Not a valid command: / 
[error] /sbt 
[error]  ^
```

How to build Spark on Windows?

Comment: That's weird to read about your attempts to build `1.1.0` while the error message references `0.9.0-incubating`. Can you explain the difference?

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE** Please see my comment about the differences in versions.

The error `Not a valid command: /` comes from sbt that got executed and attempted to execute a command `/` (as the first character in `/sbt` string). It can only mean that you've got `sbt` shell script available in `PATH` (possibly installed separately outside the current working directory) or in the current working directory.

Just execute `sbt assembly` and it should build Spark fine.

According to [the main page of Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/index.html):

> If you’d like to build Spark from scratch, visit [building Spark with Maven](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-with-maven.html).

that clearly states that the official build tool for Spark is now Maven (unfortunately).

You should be able to build a Spark package with the following command:

```
mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -DskipTests clean package
```

It worked fine for me.

Comment: > According to the main page of Spark

unfortunately this link is broken. I am trying to build Spark on Windows 7 and getting nowhere